# Wishlist - Add all to cart goes to 404 page instead

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, addtocart, wishlist

When I click "Add All to Cart" on the wishlist page, I get a 404 error and the address in the bar is http://www.blahblahblah.com/wishlist/index/allcart/. The items are not added to cart.

A slightly different error occurs if I "Add all to Cart" from the share wishlist email, it then just goes straight to homepage.

I am using Magento CE v1.9.1.0 with unchanged version of /template/wishlist/view.phtml and have not changed any core files.

It looks like it's getting the wrong url?

Comment: Please check your /template/wishlist/view.phtml file and find this code near line no 55 <form id="wishlist-allcart-form" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('*/*/allcart') ?>" method="post">. If this is there, please inspect element the same page and see if the action contains http://yourdomain/wishlist/index/allcart/

Comment: @nasir-perwaiz Yes, my code is the original unchanged code, that appears on line 55 identically. When I inspect element it shows:
<form id="wishlist-allcart-form" method="post" action="http://www.example.com/wishlist/index/allcart/">

Comment: Ok, you can debug the code by just echoing the $redirectUrl at the end of the method allcartAction() inside the class app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Controller/Abstract.php on line no 216. This should return something like this http://yourdomain/wishlist/index/index/wishlist_id/1/ . The wishlist_id could be anything

Comment: @NasirPerwaiz I've found line 217: $this->_redirectUrl($redirectUrl); What code is it that I need to add, and is it before this line or after? I've tried echo $redirectUrl;

Comment: Just write echo $redirectUrl; die(); before $this->_redirectUrl($redirectUrl); and let me know the output.

Comment: @NasirPerwaiz I have added the line echo $redirectUrl; die(); before the other line as suggested. 
I don't see any output when I click the add all button, only same as before, the 404 page with example.com/wishlist/index/allcart/ in address bar, no wishlist id is displayed in address.

(I don't know if it means anything, but when I click back from the 404 page, instead of www.example.com/wishlist/ the address reads www.example.com/wishlist/index/index/)